Mann-Whitney U Test for ranked data when there are only 4 ranks
During my university lecture I was told that for Mann-Whitney U Test on ranked data, the scale must have at least 5 different values (ranks). However, I am not able to find this information online so I am not sure if I understood it correctly?
For context, I want to use Mann-Whitney U Test to compare whether the salary range differs across two independent groups. My salary data has 4 different ranks (from low to high): 1, 2, 3, 4. Can I still use the Mann-Whitney U Test here?

"During my university lecture I was told that for Mann-Whitney U Test on ranked data, the scale must have at least 5 different values (ranks)" --- was any argument for why offered? If you properly account for the impact of the pattern of ties on the distribution of the statistic under H0, what's the issue, exactly? Is it one of low power compared to some alternative approach?

@Glen_b it wasn't clarified why it has to have at least 5 ranks, hence I came here for clarification. However, I found no evidence for that statement and it seems that I can just go ahead and apply the test for my data. Regarding the ties, it seems that python applies correction for them automatically, so I didn't do anything else to handle them, and the result showed statistically significant differences between classes. So I think I got my answer now. Thanks!

If your sample sizes are smallish, you can always use simulation to check that the test still gives about the right type I error rate (i.e. that you rejection rate is close to $\alpha$ when H0 is true with the sort of distribution you have (combined across groups naturally, given you're dealing with the case where H0 is true).

I've been doing some simulations, with 4 options and a variety of distributions over those 4 options.
The Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test seems fairly level-robust to this situation.
At $n_1=n_2=10$, the attained type I error rate hovers around 4.4% on the various multinomial distributions I tried - which is roughly the same as what's attainable when there's no ties at all.
Similarly with $n_1=n_2=15$ (where the attainable type I error rates are around 4.5% whether there's 4 options or an infinite number of them).
I also tried 3 options. That also seems okay and again it seems that it's not particularly sensitive to the distribution over the options.
The advice seems misplaced -- or rather I can't discern any good reason for it, at least as far as significance level goes. I may get a chance to investigate power. I expect I'd see some impact there, but not necessarily so much that I'd be inclined to worry.
